# The possibility of creating an OS independent GUI software

Tags: windows, api, user-interface, operating-system

Greetings , I have a few questions that need experts' help to demystify it.

**Question:**

1.)Can a GUI be created without using any framework or API like *GDI* and *DirectX*??

2.)How microsoft develop the GUI environment for his OS??

3.)Is it possible that I could get knowledge about creating a GUI which run during booting without relying on an OS??Does it require any special tools which we do not own at home but is available in microsoft??

4.)Any book recommended for me to know more about GUI development of OS like windows and linux??

Thanks for spending time reading my question , your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this field but to my knowledge:

1. Without considering your question #3, Yes, use a programming language (PL), but if you consider PL's as framework then NO, or even if it's possible, it is certainly not practical.  Even [Assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) (machine language) is a programming language.
2. To help understand the answer to this question, I suggest you read [what an operating system is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and [how it is created](http://www.osnews.com/story/2691).  MS Windows (depending on the version) is written using PL: C, C++, C#, and Assembly.  They used what we consider now as "low-level" programming to create their GUI's.
3. I find this question conflicting, I believe you need an OS to run a GUI.  Because an operating system is responsible for connecting your hardware together (e.g. where to output the display, where to get the inputs like keyboard and mouse, etc).  If you want, create an OS yourself but again, I find this very impractical.  What you can do is start learning how to [create GUI from Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646273/custom-linux-gui-where-to-begin) or even build your own minimalistic OS from [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/).  I recommended Linux because it's free and mature (relatively stable, has tons of documentation and internet references)!
4. I can't recommend any specific book, but types of book: Programming Languages and Operating Systems.  Also, you can find all the resources you need on the internet.  You just need to know exactly what questions you are looking an answer for.

But if you simply want to create a GUI that can run on most Operating Systems, [this has been the aim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere) of [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29).  Java uses a virtual machine to do this.  Of course there are other options too, you can research about it. If it's already available that suits your needs and it's **legally** free, use it. It will save you a lot of effort. :)